# CDA kettle over kettleTransFromFile diffren behaviour vs Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: kettle, data-integration, pentaho-cde, pentaho-data-integration

I create in pentaho server a form using CDE. This form is a table with some input fields. On button click is generate an array which is send as parameter value. IN db table i have 3 columns: alfa, beta, gamma.

```
//var data = JSON.stringify(array);
var data = [
 {"alfa":"some txt","beta":"another text","gamma": 23},
 {"alfa":"stxt","beta":"anoxt","gamma": 43}
]
```

I create a kettle transformation which is run as expected. This 2 rows of array are inserted in database, but when i run same kettle transformation using CDA kettle over kettleTransFromFile in Pentaho, only first row is inserted.
This is my transformation:

[image]

1. Get Variable: data(string)
2. Modified Java Script Value: **data_decode** contain the json array

   var data_decode = eval(data.toString());
3. JSON Input : alfa - $..[0].alpha, beta - $..[0].beta, gamma -$..[0].gamma
4. tableinsert - insert in database.

... From spoon, kettle command line all are OK, but not from Pentaho.
What is wrong?

Thank you!
Geo

---

**UPDATE**

Maybe it's miss configuration or a bug or a feauture, but i don't use this method. I find a simple method: i create a **scriptable over scripting** datasource with a simple java code inside (using beanshell). Now it's work as expected. I'll move this form inside a Sparkl plugin. Thank you.

This question, still remains open, maybe somebody want to try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use a correct JSONPath to eliminate side effects: `$.*.alpha`